# Hinduism opposite of a third eye

Tags: gods, history

Is there the concept of someone who sees futures that shouldn't exist or shouldn't be?

I know about the third eye.

Comment: Your statement - Is there the concept of someone who sees futures that shouldn't exist or shouldn't be try? - lacks clarity.  Please expand it for understanding the question.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv escapes time travel is my response.

Comment: I could not still understand.  I am asking for clarity because if the question is not focused it is liable to be closed.  Please understand.

Comment: Third Eye ain't for future seeing.   Are you looking for a person or a concept reference which can see the future which is yet to happen? If so, ask question accordingly. Currently it looks unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what exactly your question is. I understood it relates to superior perception or faculties.

Nostradamus and Pothuluri Veerabrahmam garu had a given faculty to see the future most probably by birth or were gifted through a blessing transferred by a more spiritually powerful person or deity. The former recorded his vision and the latter communicated it through word of mouth.

The ability may have been further developed by Yogic sadhana.. or spinal kundalini awakening.

From a physical viewpoint neural chemistry cannot be ruled out, it may be involving the pineal gland. Creativity by endorphin release and neuro-transmission (e.g.,the Buddha) by fasting, altered consciousness and perceptive states by drug administration are not unknown.

Comment: Nostradamus' "predictions" are [not really prophecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostradamus#Scholarly_rebuttal). The reason people think some of his "predictions" have come true is due to a phenomenon called [Barnum effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnum_effect). I suspect same is the case with Potuluru Veerabrahmendra.

Comment: Maybe. Old knowledge gets formatted in historical hindsight.